# Shopware 6: Docker exec system:config:set command fails with value containing spaces in Git Bash script

Tags: bash, docker, git-bash, shopware6, docker-exec

I'm running Shopware 6 in Docker and trying to set a config value using the `system:config:set` command:

```rb
docker exec  $SHOPWARE_CONTAINER_ID php bin/console system:config:set -j $PLUGIN_NAME.config.autoPublishStars 3 Stars
```

This works fine for other values, but fails when the value contains spaces between 3 and Stars.

```rb
Too many arguments to "system:config:set" command, expected arguments "key" "value".
```

It seems to interpret the spaced value as multiple arguments rather than a single string value. I have also tried `"3 Stars"` and `3Stars` but none of these worked. Kindly, let me know how I can assign the string to the config property.

Comment: What error do you get when you use quotation marks? The same?

Comment: I just noticed that you are setting the "j" option for JSON, have you tried it without?

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: You definitely do need quotes. For me it worked (but tested without docker) Which error are you getting when supplying "3 Stars"  or "3Stars" - I cannot believe you are getting the same error message. When not using quotes, it's pretty clear you get this message. You could also try something like `'"3 Stars"'` - maybe docker exec is "eating" the quotes. Also please try to go into a shell of the container with `docker exec -it /bin/sh` and execute `bin/console` there to narrow down the problem